# Sencha Touch. Works fine in browser, but only show blank page on iphone

Tags: extjs, touch, screen

**The code:**

```
Ext.define("app.view.Login", {


extend:'Ext.Panel',
fullscreen:true,
xtype:'login',


requires:[


'Ext.form.Panel',
'Ext.Button',
'Ext.field.Text',
'Ext.field.Password',
'app.view.Main'


],


config:{


fullscreen:true,
cls:'login',
style:'background-image:url("img/login.png"); background-size:100% auto;',


scrollable:false,

items:[]
}
...
```

**In my app.js:**

```
launch:function () {
Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('App.view.Login'));
}
```

It works fine in Chrome browser, but only show a blank page on iphone. Does anyone know what may cause this problem? Did I do something wrong? Or is it a bug?

Comment: have u figured out how to overcome this issue? I am facing this issue now and found no solution for this yet from yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I tried what you have done works for me in iOS simulator 5.0. The problem maybe adding app.view.Main. Try without it in requires also it is enough if you give fullscreen:true in config. Dont repeat yourself.